# Compiling VLCKit in Snow Leopard

Tags: cocoa, compilation, vlc

I tried to build VLC and VLCKit in several different ways. I need x86_64 and garbage collection supported. I follow Wiki Page Mac OS X Framework but I don't know what I do wrong.

I use git
    $ git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc.git

- I open ./vlc/projects/macosx/framework/VLCKit.xcodeproj
- I make sure the VLCKit target is selected. I found "Build Everything" target selected.
- I select "VLCKit" (Image 2). (when I tried "Build Everything" I found errors too)
- I rightclick on target and build

I found 4 error.

More info in this post: [Post in Official VLC Forum](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=85207)

What's wrong? Where I could find VLCKit Garbage Collection Supported binary? Thank!

Answer (score 1):

According to this reply on the VLC forum VLCKit does not support Garbage Collection at the moment: [Post in VLC Forum](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=84214)

Concerning compiling VLCKit in general try this:

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc/vlc-1.1.git vlc-1.1
cd vlc-1.1/projects/macosx/framework
xcodebuild -alltargets -configuration Release -project VLCKit.xcodeproj ARCHS="x86_64" -sdk macosx10.6
```

You specifically need the vlc-1.1.git branch which seems to be the stable variant. It's all written up in this [post](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=84214) i referenced above.